# How to continuously integrate pugjs into rendering html?

Tags: javascript, html, pug, frontend

I am trying to read the PUG JS docs at https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

But to use it I have to run the command each time I save the .pug file for it to render

I want something like what sass has :

`sass --watch style.sass`

Can I do that with Pug -jade ?

Answer (score 1):

Pug itself can't use do this, as far as I know. I recommend to use a build-system like `gulp`. It offers a watcher (`gulp.watch`) which automatically triggers the build on file-change:

```
gulp.task('watch-views', ['default'], function () {
    gulp.watch(viewsRootDir + '**/*.pug', ['views']);
});
```

You can also look at dedicated `gulp` plugins which accomplish this (e.g. https://github.com/lishid/gulp-watch-pug).

Answer (score 1):

Similarly like Gulp, Grunt also can render Pug to HTML continuously.

You can try to use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-pug

And to make it rendered whenever file patterns are added, changed or deleted, you can use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch